# Which HTML element makes the most sense for code annotation?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I'm working on a web app that has code listings. Certain lines of code have notes attached to them (think comments, but not inline code comments - more like an author explaining something).

When a user hovers over the footnote type indicator, a tooltip will display the comment.

[Example code on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JC49m/)

**Now the questions**

1. What element would make the most sense to wrap the comment indicator
   in? I toyed with the idea of `<mark>`, but I get the feeling that's a
   stretch. Somebody suggested the `<object>` tag could actually make sense.
   Again, not sure.
2. Is there an element that the actual footnotes (we're calling them
   annotations) should be wrapped in?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: But this isn't really a citation. `<cite>` is more for bibliography style references (e.g.: book title). http://html5doctor.com/element-index/#c

Comment: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#footnotes  ?

Comment: Thanks Marc. The `<sup>` is definitely what I've seen used before. It just feels rather meaningless. Then again, I guess it has more meaning than a `<span>`. Wrapping in an `<a>` certainly makes sense, however.

Comment: Yeah. Footnotes would be nice, but since html pages are effectively infinitely high, they don't make structural sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was thinking that `<aside>` might be useful, but probably a footnote pattern is really the closest match.

Wikipedia uses `<sup id="cite_ref-N"><a href="#cite_note-N">N</a></cite>` for the indicator and `<li id="cite_note-N">Note</li>` for the note. You could do worse than follow that.

Comment: I was trying to think if using `<aside>` could make sense for the note container. Could be. Then again, I may just be trying to cram meaning into something that doesn't really matter all that much. :) The `<sup><a>` wrap seems like it'll be the best bet. Thanks for the input.